# Is MS office required on server to use Microsoft.Excel.interop

Tags: c#, excel

I have created a merge excel program in my application using Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel. But when deployed on IIS server I am getting error. Regarding that error I searched many articles and tried but got no successfs. So please can you verify this?

Comment: Yes, it is.  Its also very much not recommended to use Office Automation from ASP.Net in the first place so its best to find an alternative (OpenXML for example)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is required.

But, you should not use Office interop on a server.  The problem is that Office apps require a graphical user session to work properly.  On the other hand, Windows service apps and IIS run without one.  This is [officially](https://support.microsoft.com/en-gb/help/257757/considerations-for-server-side-automation-of-office) not supported and not recommended.  If you do, you will encounter random crashes and resource leaks.

If you want to generate or modify Excel files, use [OpenXML SDK](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/open-xml/open-xml-sdk).

EDIT:  You may want to use [Spreadsheet Gear](https://www.spreadsheetgear.com/).  I can recommend it from personal experience in a web-app that manipulated existing Excel sheets with complex formulas.

Comment: Here's a link to the page on MS website saying [don't do it](https://support.microsoft.com/en-gb/help/257757/considerations-for-server-side-automation-of-office) if you wanted to incorporate that into your answer.

Comment: Thanks, @Damien_The_Unbeliever, I also just remembered the name of a library I have successfully used.